# Form of $k$ when both $6k-1$ and $6k+1$ are primes

Tags: number-theory, twin-primes

After a quick glance at [sequence A007693](https://oeis.org/A007693) it seems that the following is true:

> if $p$ and $p+2$ are prime, then $\frac{p+1}{6}$ is prime.

***Questions:***

a) Is it the case? If not, what is the smallest counterexample?

b) If true, is the proof: (b.1) elementary? (b.2) involving elaborate known results? (b.3) conditional on some strong conjecture?

***Note:***

This is not asking whether twin primes are always of the form $6k\pm 1$, which is true and easy;  it is also not asking if there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic progression $6m-1$.

**Thank you for any help !**

Comment: False. $59,61$ is the smallest counterexample.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused and thought the sequence was showing all values of k such that 6k+/-1 are prime, but I now realize this is not the case! Oops...

Answer (score 2):

Take $p=3$. Then $p$ and $p+2$ are both prime but $\frac{p+1}{6}=\frac{4}{6}$ is not even an integer.

Comment: The OP was talking about primes $>3$, since all such primes are of the form $6k\pm1$.